# Converting and segmenting a collection of 44100hz, 16-bit mono wav files into 16kHz, 16-bit mono wav files

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound

I need to break apart a large collection of wav files into smaller segments, and convert them into 16 khz, 16-bit mono wav files. To segment the wav files, I downloaded a `WavFile` class from the following site: [WavFile Class](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html). I tweaked it a bit to allow skipping an arbitrary number of frames. Using that class, I created a `WavSegmenter` class that would read a source wav file, and copy the frames between time x and time y into a new wav file. The start time and end time I can get from a provided XML file, and I can get the frames using `sample rate * time`. My problem is I do not know how to convert the sample rates from 44,100 to 16,000.

Currently, I am looking into Java's Sound API for this. I didn't consult it initially, because I found the guides long, but if it's the best existing option, I am willing to go through it. I would still like to know if there's another way to do it, though. Finally, I would like to know whether I should completely adapt Java's Sound API, and drop the `WavFile` class I am currently using. To me, it looks sound, but I would just like to be sure.

Thank you very much, in advance, for your time.

Comment: do you really want to do it in Java? If you can use/invoke an external program, I'd go with *sox* : http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Comment: My groupmates and I were considering doing it manually with Audacity, but that would take way too long. The reason I chose Java is because it's my strongest language, but as long as I can automate converting the files, I wouldn't mind breaking the segmenting and converting into two separate runs.

Comment: Well, `sox` is a command line program, you can automate the process. And you can also do the segmenting with `sox`

Comment: I just read that part now, too. I honestly wish I'd asked this sooner hahaha! I'll stick to working out Java's Sound API because I've already blown 3 days learning, absorbing, and understanding the basics of the wav file format. I ended up reviewing endianness, bits and bytes, and all sorts of low-level things because of it. Thanks for suggesting SoX though. I am truly grateful. I can't really choose this as an answer, though, cause it isn't Java-based, and some other guy might need a Java-based answer. Still, Thank You so much.

Comment: It's ok. To do manually the 44.1K to 16K conversion, it's very difficult not very trivial. One simple (not the best quality) could be: 1) decimate by 2 (averaging) to go to 22.050Hz 2) then do linear interpolation (eg: see my related explanation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48903/2d-array-downsampling-and-upsampling-using-bilinear-interpolation )

Comment: You're going down to 16kHz but leaving the bit-depth at 16-bit?  That is a very odd configuration.  Why not use something more common, such as 22.050kHz at 8 bit?

Comment: I'm using a speech recognition library called sphinx-4. It uses 16kHz 16bit mono wav files for its training. Unfortunately, I'm not too good with the lower-end aspects of computing such as DSP, fourier transforms, etc.; the specialization I took focuses more on things like the differences between Agile and CMMI, web-development, and software development. I've no idea why 22050Hz, 8-bit is more popular.

Comment: @leonbloy: how would you go about calling sox from a java program? Use ssystem? or JNI?

Comment: ProcessBuilder is the easy way.

Comment: In my comment from yesterday i meant: "44.1K to 16K conversion, it's not very difficult nor very trivial"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the hardest part of your task is re-sampling from 44.1K to 16K samples per sec. It would have been much simpler to downsample to 22K or 11K from there! You will need to do some interpolation there.

**EDIT:** After further review and discussion with OP I believe the right choice for this situation is to go with Java Sound API because it provides methods for conversion between different sound file formats, including different sampling rates. Sticking with the WavFile API would require re-sampling which is quite complicated to implement in a 44.1K to 16K conversion case.

Comment: I have no idea what interpolation is. I'm reading Java's Sound API know to understand it, but I initially browsed through a part that hinted that it supported conversion. Here's where I found it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html#114640

Comment: OK. I see now that it allows for re-sampling during conversion from one format to another. I don't believe I've seen that functionality in the other API you mentioned. Then, I guess, the choice is clear.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go with the Sound API, and fall back on SoX if I get too lazy. If you'll kindly edit your answer to reflect this new information, I'll be glad to click on the magical green checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SampleRateConverter.html. I suppose  This would help you...